# Fourier Coefficients in arbitrary Hilbert Spaces

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Say we have an orthonormal basis $\{e_n\}$ for a infinite Hilbert Space $H$.  I want to prove that any vector $x=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\langle x, e_n\rangle e_n$.  I don't know where to start.  Could I have  any help?

Comment: I took the liberty of correcting "$<x,e_n>$" to "$\langle x,e_n\rangle e_n$". Clearly $x$ isn't a sum of scalars unless $H = \mathbb K$.

Comment: Thank you.  My mistake.  I didn't read over this after I posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the meaning of 
$$
x=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \langle x,e_n\rangle e_n?
$$
This is
$$
x=\lim_{m\to\infty}\sum_{n=1}^m \langle x,e_n\rangle e_n,
$$
or in other words
$$
\left\|x-\sum_{n=1}^m \langle x,e_n\rangle e_n\right\|\to 0,
$$
as $m\to\infty$. Now recall $\|y\|^2=\langle y,y\rangle$, and try to show that the preceding limit goes to $0$.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the set of all vectors of that form. Prove that it is a (closed) subspace, and that its orthogonal is zero. Then it has to be all of $H$.